# R code containing Rcpp function runs twice as fast on Mac, than on a much more powerful Windows machine

Tags: c++, r, macos, windows-10, rcpp

I have written R code containing Rcpp function, which in turn calls other cpp functions through inline, on my Mac. I have switched to a Windows machine with a much more powerful cpu and higher RAM, but the same code takes on average twice as much to run on this new machine.

my R session info on Mac is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ojSA.png)

and that of the Windows machine is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkwGV.png)

As a clear example, this small function in my code (lik2altcpp.cpp)

```
#ifndef __lik2altcpp__
#define __lik2altcpp__

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include "RcppArmadillo.h"
#include "FactorialLog.cpp"
using namespace arma;
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
inline vec lik2altF(vec p,int k,double eps) {


  wall_clock timer;
  timer.tic();

  double ptie=0,arg11=0,arg12=0,arg21=0,arg22=0,ptb=0,pu1=0,pu2=0;
  double p1,p2,ps;
  vec prob(2);

  if (p(0)==0) p1=10e-20; else p1=p(0);
  if (p(1)==0) p2=10e-20; else p2=p(1);
  if (p(2)==0) ps=10e-20; else ps=p(2);

  for (int i=0;i<=k;i++)
  {
    if (i!=0)
    {

      ptie=ptie+ exp(FactorialLog(2*k-i-1)-(FactorialLog(i-1)+FactorialLog(k-i)+FactorialLog(k-i))+i*log(ps)+(k-i)*log(p1)+(k-i)*log(p2));

    }

    if(i!=k) 
    {

      arg11=arg11+exp(FactorialLog(k+i-1)-(FactorialLog(i)+FactorialLog(k-1))+k*log(p1)+i*log(p2)); //first argument of the P(1) 
      arg12=arg12+exp(FactorialLog(k+i-1)-(FactorialLog(i)+FactorialLog(k-1))+i*log(p1)+k*log(p2)); //first argument of the P(2) 

    } 

    if((i!=0) && (i!=k))
    {
      for(int j=0; j<=(k-i-1);j++)
      {

        arg21=arg21+ exp(FactorialLog(k+j-1)-(FactorialLog(i-1)+FactorialLog(k-i)+FactorialLog(j))+ i*log(ps)+(k-i)*log(p1)+j*log(p2)) + exp(FactorialLog(k+j-1)-(FactorialLog(i)+FactorialLog(k-i-1)+FactorialLog(j)) + i*log(ps)+(k-i)*log(p1)+j*log(p2)); //second argument of the P(1)
        arg22=arg22+ exp(FactorialLog(k+j-1)-(FactorialLog(i-1)+FactorialLog(k-i)+FactorialLog(j))+ + i*log(ps)+j*log(p1)+(k-i)*log(p2)) + exp(FactorialLog(k+j-1)-(FactorialLog(i)+FactorialLog(k-i-1)+FactorialLog(j)) + i*log(ps)+j*log(p1)+(k-i)*log(p2)); //second argument of the P(2)
      }

    }

  } 
//summing up the terms of the prob. formula
    pu1=arg11+arg21 ;
    pu2=arg12+arg22;

    // ptb=(p1+eps*ps)/(p1+p2+2*eps*ps);   //the actual formula for ptb
      ///////////REVERT THE CHANGES AFTER THE TEST ////////////////
      ptb=.5;

//Calculating probabilities

  prob(0)=pu1+ptb*ptie;
  prob(1)=pu2+(1-ptb)*ptie;

  double n = timer.toc();

  cout << "number of seconds: " << n;

  return prob;
}
#endif //__lik2altcpp__
```

along with the function it includes(FactorialLog.cpp):

```
#ifndef __FactorialLog__
#define __FactorialLog__


#include "RcppArmadillo.h"
using namespace arma;
using namespace Rcpp;



// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
inline double FactorialLog(int n)
{

  if (n < 0)
  {
    std::stringstream os;
    os << "Invalid input argument (" << n 
       << "); may not be negative";
    throw std::invalid_argument( os.str() );

  }
  else if (n > 254)
  {
    const double Pi = 3.141592653589793;
    double x = n + 1;
    return (x - 0.5)*log(x) - x + 0.5*log(2*Pi) + 1.0/(12.0*x);
  }
  else
  {
    double lf[] =        
      {
      0.000000000000000,
      0.000000000000000,
      0.693147180559945,
      1.791759469228055,
      3.178053830347946,
      4.787491742782046,
      6.579251212010101,
      8.525161361065415,
      10.604602902745251,
      12.801827480081469,
      15.104412573075516,
      17.502307845873887,
      19.987214495661885,
      22.552163853123421,
      25.191221182738683,
      27.899271383840894,
      30.671860106080675,
      33.505073450136891,
      36.395445208033053,
      39.339884187199495,
      42.335616460753485,
      45.380138898476908,
      48.471181351835227,
      51.606675567764377,
      54.784729398112319,
      58.003605222980518,
      61.261701761002001,
      64.557538627006323,
      67.889743137181526,
      71.257038967168000,
      74.658236348830158,
      78.092223553315307,
      81.557959456115029,
      85.054467017581516,
      88.580827542197682,
      92.136175603687079,
      95.719694542143202,
      99.330612454787428,
      102.968198614513810,
      106.631760260643450,
      110.320639714757390,
      114.034211781461690,
      117.771881399745060,
      121.533081515438640,
      125.317271149356880,
      129.123933639127240,
      132.952575035616290,
      136.802722637326350,
      140.673923648234250,
      144.565743946344900,
      148.477766951773020,
      152.409592584497350,
      156.360836303078800,
      160.331128216630930,
      164.320112263195170,
      168.327445448427650,
      172.352797139162820,
      176.395848406997370,
      180.456291417543780,
      184.533828861449510,
      188.628173423671600,
      192.739047287844900,
      196.866181672889980,
      201.009316399281570,
      205.168199482641200,
      209.342586752536820,
      213.532241494563270,
      217.736934113954250,
      221.956441819130360,
      226.190548323727570,
      230.439043565776930,
      234.701723442818260,
      238.978389561834350,
      243.268849002982730,
      247.572914096186910,
      251.890402209723190,
      256.221135550009480,
      260.564940971863220,
      264.921649798552780,
      269.291097651019810,
      273.673124285693690,
      278.067573440366120,
      282.474292687630400,
      286.893133295426990,
      291.323950094270290,
      295.766601350760600,
      300.220948647014100,
      304.686856765668720,
      309.164193580146900,
      313.652829949878990,
      318.152639620209300,
      322.663499126726210,
      327.185287703775200,
      331.717887196928470,
      336.261181979198450,
      340.815058870798960,
      345.379407062266860,
      349.954118040770250,
      354.539085519440790,
      359.134205369575340,
      363.739375555563470,
      368.354496072404690,
      372.979468885689020,
      377.614197873918670,
      382.258588773060010,
      386.912549123217560,
      391.575988217329610,
      396.248817051791490,
      400.930948278915760,
      405.622296161144900,
      410.322776526937280,
      415.032306728249580,
      419.750805599544780,
      424.478193418257090,
      429.214391866651570,
      433.959323995014870,
      438.712914186121170,
      443.475088120918940,
      448.245772745384610,
      453.024896238496130,
      457.812387981278110,
      462.608178526874890,
      467.412199571608080,
      472.224383926980520,
      477.044665492585580,
      481.872979229887900,
      486.709261136839360,
      491.553448223298010,
      496.405478487217580,
      501.265290891579240,
      506.132825342034830,
      511.008022665236070,
      515.890824587822520,
      520.781173716044240,
      525.679013515995050,
      530.584288294433580,
      535.496943180169520,
      540.416924105997740,
      545.344177791154950,
      550.278651724285620,
      555.220294146894960,
      560.169054037273100,
      565.124881094874350,
      570.087725725134190,
      575.057539024710200,
      580.034272767130800,
      585.017879388839220,
      590.008311975617860,
      595.005524249382010,
      600.009470555327430,
      605.020105849423770,
      610.037385686238740,
      615.061266207084940,
      620.091704128477430,
      625.128656730891070,
      630.172081847810200,
      635.221937855059760,
      640.278183660408100,
      645.340778693435030,
      650.409682895655240,
      655.484856710889060,
      660.566261075873510,
      665.653857411105950,
      670.747607611912710,
      675.847474039736880,
      680.953419513637530,
      686.065407301994010,
      691.183401114410800,
      696.307365093814040,
      701.437263808737160,
      706.573062245787470,
      711.714725802289990,
      716.862220279103440,
      722.015511873601330,
      727.174567172815840,
      732.339353146739310,
      737.509837141777440,
      742.685986874351220,
      747.867770424643370,
      753.055156230484160,
      758.248113081374300,
      763.446610112640200,
      768.650616799717000,
      773.860102952558460,
      779.075038710167410,
      784.295394535245690,
      789.521141208958970,
      794.752249825813460,
      799.988691788643450,
      805.230438803703120,
      810.477462875863580,
      815.729736303910160,
      820.987231675937890,
      826.249921864842800,
      831.517780023906310,
      836.790779582469900,
      842.068894241700490,
      847.352097970438420,
      852.640365001133090,
      857.933669825857460,
      863.231987192405430,
      868.535292100464630,
      873.843559797865740,
      879.156765776907600,
      884.474885770751830,
      889.797895749890240,
      895.125771918679900,
      900.458490711945270,
      905.796028791646340,
      911.138363043611210,
      916.485470574328820,
      921.837328707804890,
      927.193914982476710,
      932.555207148186240,
      937.921183163208070,
      943.291821191335660,
      948.667099599019820,
      954.046996952560450,
      959.431492015349480,
      964.820563745165940,
      970.214191291518320,
      975.612353993036210,
      981.015031374908400,
      986.422203146368590,
      991.833849198223450,
      997.249949600427840,
      1002.670484599700300,
      1008.095434617181700,
      1013.524780246136200,
      1018.958502249690200,
      1024.396581558613400,
      1029.838999269135500,
      1035.285736640801600,
      1040.736775094367400,
      1046.192096209724900,
      1051.651681723869200,
      1057.115513528895000,
      1062.583573670030100,
      1068.055844343701400,
      1073.532307895632800,
      1079.012946818975000,
      1084.497743752465600,
      1089.986681478622400,
      1095.479742921962700,
      1100.976911147256000,
      1106.478169357800900,
      1111.983500893733000,
      1117.492889230361000,
      1123.006317976526100,
      1128.523770872990800,
      1134.045231790853000,
      1139.570684729984800,
      1145.100113817496100,
      1150.633503306223700,
      1156.170837573242400,
      };
    return lf[n];
  }
}
#endif //__FactorialLog__
```

runs three times as fast on Mac as it does on Windows. You can try it e.g. with these inputs:

```
> lik2altF(p=c(.3,.3,.4),k=10000,eps=1000)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is not enough information in the question to produce a meaningful answer. A [mcve] would help. As would information on what *exact* tool chain is used on the different platforms.

Comment: Different operating systems are, well "different".  So the problem is your assumption that the performance should be equivalent.

Comment: JesperJuhl: in my opinion the question is very interesting Dirk: yes but why. This is the question

Comment: This depends on many things. What compiler is used on each of these platforms, with which options (e.g. optimization level). But most importantly this depends on the actual code.

Comment: Having edited the initial question, I'd appreciate your answer. @DirkEddelbuettel , if Rcpp developers are to expect such a huge performance gap across operating systems, I think this should be mentioned upfront in the documentation because it raises serious reproducibility concerns.